# How to update a ContentFile's content (by overwriting the file)

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to keep the same filename of a `FileField` in my `UpdateView` when I update the file content.

It's a css file that `CreateView` generates by rendering a template with the form data as the context. Here's an extract of that logic:

```
instance = form.save(commit=False)
t = TemplateResponse(self.request, 'base.css', {"cssform": form})
t.render()
css_string = t.content
file_content = ContentFile(css_string)
instance.css_file.save(file_name, file_content)
```

I'm not having the same success with the `UpdateView`:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    instance = self.object
    filename = instance.css_file
    t = TemplateResponse(self.request, 'base.css', {"cssform": form})
    t.render()
    css_string = t.content
    filedata = ContentFile(css_string)
    instance.css_file.save(filename, filedata)
    super(CSSUpdate, self).save(form)
```

The error is:

> join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'FieldFile'

The error is provoked on this line:

```
    instance.css_file.save(filename, filedata)
```

The traceback is short:

> Traceback:
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/posixpath.py" in join
>     82.             if b.startswith(sep):

How do I overwrite that old file with my new content?
I'm using django 1.10, python 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`instance.css_file` is a [`FieldFile`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile) object, not a filename. You should use the name instead:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    instance = self.object
    filename = instance.css_file.name
    ...
    instance.css_file.save(filename, filedata)
    super(CSSUpdate, self).save(form)
```